# Android Application Cant find more then 4.x(L Preview ) I want 5.0

Tags: android, eclipse

Hello i have install [IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bcGC.png)

All 5.0 Files but when i am creating project in eclipse i m not getting target more then 4.X Look here [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I68JB.png) 
So what should i do

Comment: If you scroll up in the SDK Manager, you will see a Tools category. Do you have the latest tools installed?

Comment: Yes Latest one 24Api but it is asking to update should i update it ?

Comment: Yes. IIRC, Eclipse would filter out SDKs based on the available tool support. Bear in mind that official Eclipse support from Google ended ~6 months ago.

Comment: But i dont need 24Api Tool then why should i install it :(

Comment: I Updated 25.1.7 Android SDK Tool But it is still not workign